# Adding jmp instructions

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm, intel, instrumentation, testcocoon

I want to add **harmless** `unconditional branches` after every jmp-like instruction in the binary to ensure that the **fall through branch** can be observed when we keep a record of branch instructions executed using Intel's `Last Branch Record`. Like in this code :

```
if(a==0){
 f1(); 
}
else{
 f2();
}
```

When the `else` part is executed, a `jne` instruction might be executed. But, there is no `jmp-related` instruction to observe that the `if` part is executed.

- Is there a tool to **statically add** these `unconditional jmp` instructions for conditional statements at the **binary level** or at **source level** ?
- I tried using `TestCocoon` like this : `csgcc --cs-branch -g test.c` But, the instrumentation overhead is quite high (around 3X the original executable). I think I am not using the right compiler options. It would be great if you could provide some pointers for adding harmless unconditional branches with low instrumentation overhead.

Answer (score 2):

[Pin](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/pin-a-dynamic-binary-instrumentation-tool) is a good binary instrumentation tool for X86. You can easily achieve with it what you intend.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a tool to do this **statically**, although it requires source code producer cooperation. Here is a [video where some developers used llvm to try and find race conditions](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CPnRS1nv3_s). However the advised PIN tool can do precisely what you want (or at least as described).

A good question I think you should ask yourself is whether or not this is profiling is something that must be done statically. For that matter, I point you toward [dynamic analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_program_analysis). Another question to ask is whether or not you should really be doing this from the ground up; the availablility of tools that the community has made is rather extensive. [Here's a good profiler](https://code.google.com/p/likwid/), but I'm not sure that this exact one suits your needs because you haven't described your needs so well...

Also, about overhead-I think that just about any instrumentation tool is going to add a *lot* of overhead. To address this, what I would say is that the effort required to produce highly efficient profiling is generally not worth it. Unless you are making a profiling library, I would advise against it, since all you want are the results of the instrumentation.